# Systematic review of the uses of the axiom of choice

Tags: axiom-of-choice

Is there some systematic study of which mathematical results requires the axiom of choice? A book or a review article. I don't mean only results without which some areas of mathematics would be hard to work with (for example, that $\mathbb{R}$ is Fréchet whose demonstration relies on the axiom of choice if I am not mistaken). But also the various kind of "monster" made possible by the axiom of choice (for example, non-Lebesgue-measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The book "Consequences of the axiom of choice" is excellent, but rather high level. Perhaps more accessible is [Herrlich's wonderful book](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540309895), which was what I learned from initially. [Jech also has a book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486466248) on the axiom of choice, but this focuses more on building models where choice fails/holds in specific ways, not general applications/implications of the axiom.

Comment: The chapter titles are enticing indeed: Disasters without choice, Disasters with choice, Disasters either way.

Answer (score 2):

There's the book 'Consequences of the Axiom of Choice' which can be found [here](http://bookstore.ams.org/surv-59).

Maybe there is some pdf online or something that's cheaper or available for free, but this definitely fits the bill.

Comment: Related: [the choiceless grapher](https://github.com/ioannad/jeffrey) is based on the Howard-Rubin data.